# Exclude Taxonomy Terms from Template Via Back End?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm wondering if you can help me work through an issue or provide alt ideas.

I have an archive displaying a list of custom tax terms in a grid view.

My client needs to be able to turn on/off the terms from displaying in the grid. If these were posts this would be easy because I could simply have him check/uncheck a category for the post. However, taxonomies don't have that feature out of the box.

Does anyone know how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Thanks to @Tarukus as his answer was helpful. Again, my goal was to display terms (not posts) from my custom taxonomy via an on/off switch. To do this, I used Advanced Custom Fields and created a "Select" field with two values (on/off). Once this field was applied to my taxonomy I could select a value for each term. The default value was set to "off".  Now to display only the terms set to "on" I had to add the following code in my template file - and of course set some terms to "on".

```
 <?php

    $terms = get_terms('MYTAXONOMY', array());      

    if($terms)

    {

        echo '<ul>';

        foreach($terms as $term)

        {


            if( get_field('ENTERCUSTOMFIELDSLUG', 'ENTERMYTAXONOMY_'.$term->term_id) != 'ENTERFIELDVALUE' ) 
                        continue;

            echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</a></li>';

        }

        echo '</ul>';

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to accomplish this using Advanced Custom Fields: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/taxonomy/

Field groups, like the taxonomy field, can be assigned to templates. Editing the taxonomy archive page, the user would see checkboxes (or radio buttons, or a select menu) for the taxonomy terms.

In the corresponding "taxonomy archive" template (from link above)...

```
<?php 

$terms = get_field('taxonomy_field_name');

if( $terms ): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>

        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Make sure to provide some context for links, @taruckus. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there." I know why you're recommending this, but it's not clear from the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at ACF. Could you provide any more info about how it may help?

Comment: Sure all; post expanded.

Comment: Hi, just an update, ACF has helped me achieve this. You code above I think would work, but I needed something a little more specific, please see the answer I added.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

From what I understand you want a filter to display posts that belong to a specific list of terms. As default you display all posts making all terms enabled. In order to disable a term from being displayed you need to exclude it from the loop.

```
<?php
// we get all the terms of the taxonomy
$terms = get_terms('mytaxonomy');

/*
excludeTerms=term1,term2,term3
as a GET parameter created by the exclude form
*/
$excludeList = array();

if (isset($_GET['excludeTerms']) && !empty($_GET['excludeTerms'])) {
    $excludeList = explode(',', $_GET['excludeTerms']);
}

/*
how to display the available terms
the permalink is get_term_link($term, $taxonomy);
*/
$termList = '';
if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        if (!in_array($term->name, $excludeList)) {
            echo "<li class='enabled-term'>" . $term->name . "</li>";
            if ($termList == '') {
                $termList = $term->name;
            } else {
                $termList .= ', ' . $term->name;
            }
        } else {
            echo "<li class='disabled-term'>" . $term->name . "</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

if ($termList != '') {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'posttype',
        'mytaxonomy' => $termList
    );
} else {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'posttype'
    );
}
query_posts($args);
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    the_title();
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
    <style>
        .enabled-term, .disabled-term {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .disabled-term {
            color: #ddd;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('.enabled-term').live('click', function () {
                // so that one term remains enabled
                if ($('.enabled-term').length == 1)
                    return;
                $(this).removeClass('enabled-term').addClass('disabled-term');
                navigate();
            });
            $('.disabled-term').live('click', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('disabled-term').addClass('enabled-term');
                navigate();
            });
            function navigate() {
                list = $('.disabled-term');
                excludeList = '';
                for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    if (excludeList == '')
                        excludeList = $(list[i]).text();
                    else
                        excludeList += ',' + $(list[i]).text();
                }
                window.location = window.location.origin + 
                                  window.location.pathname + 
                                  '?excludeTerms=' + excludeList;
            };
        }(jQuery));
    </script>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms for term list
http://codex.wordpress.org/query_posts for the loop (Example 5 for tax & terms)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I was looking for.

Comment: Take it as an idea not a solution. It may lead you somewhere.

Comment: @streetfire you are talking about a back-end solution?

Comment: yes a backend solution was what I needed. I was able to achieve it using Advanced Custom fields and a custom query.